# Put a variable as A Labels Text in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a project which generates a random number by taking a input from a `textBox` then after the click of a button, it generates the number and puts it in a `Label`.
I want to put the text like this:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string inputstr;
    inputstr = textBox1.Text;
    int inputnum;
    inputnum = Convert.ToInt32(inputstr);
    var me = new MainWindow();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int outnum = rnd.Next(inputnum);
    string outnum1 = outnum.ToString();
    Label.Text = outnum1;
}
```

but it gives an error which is:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0117  'Label' does not contain a definition for 'Text'    RandomNumber    C:\Users\Nameless\source\repos\RandomNumber\RandomNumber\MainWindow.xaml.cs 37  Active

I would be really thankful to anyone who helps.

Comment: `Label` is usually the class name. what's the _property_-name of your label?

Comment: you need ot set the name of the label(for example `label1.Text`) and not The `Label` class itself

Comment: If the name of the component is `Label`, you should set it's `Content` property. `TextBlock` has a `Text` property, Label doesn't.

Comment: Wherever you got your example from, it's for WinForms NOT WPF. [puny winforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=net-5.0#examples) vs. [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.label?view=net-5.0#examples)

Comment: @XAMlMAX You mean also the RoutedEventArgs and the MainWindow? You're certainly wrong. OP is just stumbling upon the fact that a WPF Label has no Text property.

Comment: @Clemens I meant the .Text. The links I posted, link to examples of both Labels and the assignment of text and content properties respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues/points about your code.

### Label.Text

You're trying to assign the Text property to the class itself, that doesn't work. You have to assign the **Content** property to your instance, for example a label with ID *outputLabel*. This becomes: `outputLabel.Content = "Whatever...";`.

### Random not being random (enough)

Check this question on StackOverflow: [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

When declaring a Random instance **inside** your method, it won't be as random as you might want it to be. At least eclare it like following (even better would be from the answer in thlinked question):

```
private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int outnum = rnd.Next();
}
```

### Inline declaration

Your whole code could be shortened by declaring and assigning variables in one line of code:

```
private readonly Random rnd = new Random();
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string inputstr = textBox1.Text;
    int inputnum = Convert.ToInt32(inputstr);
    int outnum = rnd.Next(inputnum);
    yourLabel.Content = outnum.ToString();
}
```

### Other points

- Why type `var me = new MainWindow();` when you never use it?
- You could use `var` to declare variables
- You **should** validate input when converting from string to int

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

I just change `Label` to `label1`

and comment out `var me` statement

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string inputstr;
                inputstr = textBox1.Text;
                int inputnum;
                inputnum = Convert.ToInt32(inputstr);
                //var me = new MainWindow();
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int outnum = rnd.Next(inputnum);
                string outnum1 = outnum.ToString();
                label1.Text = outnum1;
            }
```

Comment: The WPF Label class does not have a Text property. Use Content.

Comment: I just printing number on label for that I took one label and now it has a name label1.

Comment: But `label1.Text = ...` won't compile in a WPF application. The question is not about WinForms.

Answer (score -2):

- Waarom een ​​nieuw MainWindow maken?
- Geef de link naar de tag door

---

```
<Label x:Name="label1"/>

Error-> label1.Text = "abc";

Right -> label1.Content="abc";
```

Comment: Please write in English. Answers should be usable to all users.

Comment: Sorry, Google translated the site and I thought it was in Russian